# How to specify :path and :url to save img in Paperclip, Rails 3.0.12

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Paperclip with my Rails 3.0 app in order to add an avatar to a user, and it won't save the image because the paths are off. Heres what I get:

Started GET "/profilepics/small/missing.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-11 23:38:29 -0700

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/profilepics/small/missing.png"):

My user model has:

```
    has_attached_file :profilepic, :styles => { :small => "150x150>" }
```

What should I put for :path => & :url => ?

Form looks like :

```
      <% form_for @user, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>

      <%= f.file_field :profilepic %>

      <% end %>
```

Logs look like :

Started GET "/system/profilepics/small/missing.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-12 00:33:51 -0700

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/system/profilepics/small/missing.png"):

Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.2ms)

Comment: You don't necessarily need to specify :path or :url, by default the images are saved to `:rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename`

Comment: I just keep getting a broken img upon uploading...:(

Comment: Could you add your view code as well please?

Comment: Sure, view is <%= image_tag @user.profilepic.url(:small) %>

Answer (score 3):

See my sample:

```
   has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :thumb => "50x50#", :large => "1000x1000>", :medium => "200x200#" },
     :default_url => "/system/avatars/:style/missing.png",
     :url  => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style_:filename",
     :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style_:filename"
```

- :default_url - is the path for the default image, when the user didn't upload any avatar
- "#" - this symbol is to crop image

then you can show your images as such:

```
<%=image_tag(@user.avatar.url(:thumb))%>
<%=image_tag(@user.avatar.url(:medium))%>
```

Comment: Hm, so I guess my question would be why is it displaying missing.png after I upload?

Comment: Shouldn't your form be <%= form_for in rails 3.0.12? This was a 3.0.0 change.

Comment: Check the logs after you post the form to see what's going on

Comment: Yea, it seems to be displaying the default image everytime, meaning its not saving :(

Answer (score 1):

Works now!!!

For people struggling with the same issue, here's a few important things to ALWAYS make sure and check:

1. In your form, always specify **{ :multipart => true }** otherwise, the form won't accept file attachments.

   ```
   <%= form_for @user, :html => **{ :multipart => true }** do |f| %>
   ```
2. In your user.rb (or whatever model you want to add attachments to ), make **attr_accessible :photo** (or whatever you name your attachment)
3. ALWAYS restart your server after installing a new Gem.

:) Thanks guys!!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to given url and path option if you simply want to display an image.

Use this line in show page and it will display image...

```
     <%=image_tag(@user.profilepic.url(:small))%>
```

And enjoy..............